# How to query the acoustic echo cancellation capability?

Tags: android, audio

Some Android phones have an acoustic echo cancellation component. Is there a way to detect the presence of this component from within an Android app? An API call or a system property or just anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AcousticEchoCanceller.isAvailable()`.
See [the reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler.html#isAvailable%28%29) for more info.